# Checkbox null means it's not, checkbox checked is 1

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, checkbox

I want to have it so if a checkbox is NULL, or 0, it is not a fav like it would be if the value was a one. 
Also, is there a way to limit the boxes checked to 10?

current code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//to run PHP script on submit
    if(!empty($_POST'favorites')){
    // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
        foreach($_POST['favorites[]'] as $selected){
            $query= "UPDATE u_collection SET fav = 0 WHERE username ='".$username."'"; 
            mysqli_query($db,$query);
        }
    } 
}

foreach($gems as $i){
    echo '<tr> 
    <th>'.$i->name.'</th> 
    <th><form action="collection.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox"'; 
    if($i -> fav){
        echo 'checked = "checked"';         
    }
    echo 'name="favorites[]" value='.$i->name.'></th></tr></form>'; 
}
?>
<th>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/>
</form>
```

Comment: Is `$i -> fav` a string? You could make a counter variable outside of the $gems loop and then increment in each `if($i -> fav){` that is met. Also your `$username` seems like it might open you to SQL injections.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I'm too tired but I'm having a hard time following what you mean (though it sounds logical!). Could you show me an example? Maybe that could help me a bit.

Comment: how do u get the checkbox value where it should be an error near this line `if(!empty($_POST'favorites')){`  it must be `if(!empty($_POST['favorites'])){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if it is NULL or 0 otherwise 1 I would use the empty() function

```
foreach($gems as $i){
    echo '<tr> 
    <th>'.$i->name.'</th> 
    <th><form action="collection.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox"'; 
    if(!empty($i->fav)){
        echo ' checked = "checked" ';         
    }
    echo 'name="favorites[]" value='.$i->name.'></th></tr></form>'; 
}
```

To limit the boxes which are checked to 10, I would use javascript (jQuery) as below:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('form input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function(){
        if ($('form input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 10)
        {
           $(this).removeAttr('checked');
           alert('You are only allowed to select 10 checkboxes');
        }
    });
</script>
```